# Template rendering in odoo

Tags: javascript, odoo, qweb

I want to render the template (.xml file) having id 'dashboard_example' from javascript code in odoo15. I am quite new to odoo and just got to know about Qweb2. Can you please help in finding out how should I render the template and what all dependencies and other things I need to add in order to get it working?

I tried with Qweb but it says Qweb is not defined

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import `qweb` from `web.core`:

```
import { qweb, _t } from 'web.core';
```

You can find an example in [account](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/fa58938b3e2477f0db22cc31d4f5e6b5024f478b/addons/account/static/src/js/legacy_account_selection.js) module:

```
qweb.render('accountTypeSelection', {widget: this})
```